# Click Events in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, events, click

I am writing a program that displays 2 text boxes and one label.
Whats supposed to happen; when text box 1 is clicked, the label displays "Enter your full name"
                          when text box 2 is clicked, the label displays "Enter your phone number and area code"

Help?
I have this so far

Private Sub textbox1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click, TextBox1.Enter
        Label1.Text = "Enter your full name"
    End Sub

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Click, TextBox2.Enter
    Label1.Text = "Enter your phone number and area code"
End Sub
```

Comment: There isn't really a question here, is there?

Comment: Unfortunately for me my Visual Studio Teacher isn't helpful at all. He thinks his time is more valuable than my grade.

Comment: I have the form set up and everything is done except for a couple lines. I don't know how to make the label change text when the text box is clicked

Comment: @College_Guy420: Well, to him, it is.  Don't worry though, he's far from the last boss you won't get along with.  As for the question itself... Where exactly are you stuck?  What have you tried?  Perhaps some introductory tutorials would benefit you?

Comment: If you have working code then it's helpful to post it. Ideally you would reduce it to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Keep in mind that the easier it is to tell what you've done and what you're trying to do, the more likely you are to get helpful answers.

Comment: Where can I find said tutorials? and I have this    

 Private Sub textbox1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Click

    End Sub

Comment: @College_Guy420: In the Visual Studio properties pane, there should be a listing of "events".  Highlight the text box and double-click its "focus" event.  That should create the event handler in code.  Then it's just a matter of setting the label's text in that handler.

Comment: @College_Guy420: `"Where can I find said tutorials?"` - Honestly?  Google.  I don't intend to sound harsh, but that really should be your first resource for finding things.

Comment: Posted what I have up to so you can see where I am.

Comment: @College_Guy420: So... Where are you stuck?  Are you just looking for this statement?: `Label1.Text = "Enter your full name"`

Comment: it would tell me that there is an error and wouldn't let me run when I tried the first time. I don't mean to sound stupid or anything, but this is my first language and that was my first thought. let me try again

Comment: Okay, I edited my post again, and included the code as I thought It needed to be. With this, when I click in the text box the label does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Here is basic WPF sample, please see the code and try to complete your example.

**View implementation**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<StackPanel>
    <Label x:Name="lblLabel"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtFullName" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtPhoneNumber" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" />
    <Button x:Name="btnOk" Content="OK" Click="btnOk_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;

        string labelText = "";

        if (textBox.Name == "txtFullName")
        {
            labelText = "Enter your full name.";
        }

        if (textBox.Name == "txtPhoneNumber")
        {
            labelText = "Enter your phone number and area code.";
        }

        lblLabel.Content = labelText;
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Full name: {0}, phone number: {1}", txtFullName.Text, txtPhoneNumber.Text));
    }
}
```